# Sum of vector in python 2.7,

Tags: python-2.7

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

```
m=input("M=")
for i in range(m+1):
    i=i+i**2
print i
```

This is the requirement:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWCN2.png

Comment: You do not sum the elements based on the formula, you just modify each element in the `range`. Declare a variable `sum` and then do `sum = sum + i + i**2`.

Comment: like this?   Sorry, I'm a beginner.                                                                                https://i.imgur.com/nidScne.png

Comment: Yes. Did it work?

Comment: Yes it work. Thanks so much. range shoud be m+1